# How to set the key for object array?

Tags: magento2.2, api

I have create a custom Api and I am getting the response as follws:

```
[
    [
        {
            "entity_id": "154",
            "state": "new",
            "status": "pending",
            "coupon_code": null,
            "protect_code": "98aa60a748d6b23f93c4c26eed7b53b9",
            "shipping_description": "Shipping Options - Self Collection",
            "is_virtual": "0",
            "store_id": "2",
            "customer_id": "16341",
            "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
```

But I want my response as follws:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "base_currency_code": "SGD",
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_grand_total": 107,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_shipping_amount": 0,
            "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
            "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_subtotal": 100,
            "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 107,
            "base_tax_amount": 7,
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomApi\Model;

use Vendor\CustomApi\Api\OrderHistoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class OrderHistory implements OrderHistoryInterface {

    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerFactory $customerFactory, CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
          $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    public function getOrderHistory($customerId, $direction, $pageSize, $currentPage) {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                    ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", array("eq" => $customerId));
            $CustomerResult = $customer->getData();
            $customerInfo = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $customerAttributeData = $customerInfo->__toArray();
            $VesselId = $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['customer_vessels']['value'];
            $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                            ->addAttributeToFilter("customer_vessels", array("eq" => $VesselId))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter("group_id", array("eq" => self::GROUP_ID))->load();
            $CustomerDataResult = $customerData->getData();
            if(empty($CustomerDataResult)) {
               throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                   __('Invalid customer.')
                   );
           }
            $captinId = $CustomerDataResult[0]['entity_id'];
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $captinId)->setOrder('entity_id', $direction)->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($currentPage);
            $orderInfo = $order->getData();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderItemCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection')
                    ->setOrder('entity_id', $direction);

            $orderItemCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    'sales_order', 'sales_order.entity_id=main_table.order_id', ['increment_id']
            )->where('sales_order.customer_id=?', $captinId);
            $orderResult = $orderItemCollection->getData();
            foreach ($orderInfo as $k => $v) {
                foreach ($orderResult as $k1 => $v1) {
                    if ($v1['order_id'] == $v['entity_id']) {
                        $v1['product_options'] = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($v1['product_options']);
                        $orderInfo[$k]['product_details'][] = $v1;

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __('Invalid customer.')
            );
        }
//        $managerOrder = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($orderInfo);
//        $managerOrder[] = array('Alka'=>$managerOrder);
//        $managerOrder = $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($managerOrder);
//        $object = array();
//        $object[0]['Alka'] =  $orderInfo[0];
//        $object->items = $orderInfo;
//        $orderInfo[]['total_count'] = count($orderInfo);
        return ($orderInfo);
    }

}
```

Comment: add your code..

Comment: Add your code from where you send response.

Comment: Rk Rathod and Rohan Hapanai, I have added the code.

Comment: @MeetaliGupta you can check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you can actually use a simple `json_encode` with `print_r`.
Like below:

```
print_r(json_encode(['items' => $orderInfo]));
```